# Can I chronologically order dates as characters in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have data in a .csv. The first column is dates, the second column counts a number of days. I want to plot number of days vs. date. (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmmob.jpg))

In my .csv the dates are chronological by year. In RStudio, the initial plot is chronological by the month's number.

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
#load my spreadsheet
openingData <- read_csv("daysPriorToOpening.csv")
ggplot(data = openingData) +
    geom_col(mapping = aes(x = dateOpened, y = daysPrior) +
    labs(x = "Date Opened", y = "Days prior to opening at or above 11.0")
```

That creates [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2Kb2.jpg) output, with it arranged in order by the number of the month. I like the appearance, just not the order. Someone suggested I try using as.Date()

```
openingData$dateOpened <- as.Date(openingData$dateOpened, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Then I ran the code again to graph and it plotted chronologically, but now there are large gaps. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPMTW.jpg). The dates aren't labeled as they were in the first picture; the reader has to guess the exact date.

My guess as to the different appearance is that in the first case, the dates are characters and discrete. In the second case, using as.Date() changed them to Dates and they become continuous. Is there a way to either,

1. keep the display as the first graph but order it by year, or
2. display as in the second graph but either eliminate the gaps *or* label the columns with their corresponding date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
openingData %>% 
  mutate(dateOpened = as.Date(dateOpened,"%m/%d/%y")) %>% 
  arrange(dateOpened) %>% 
  mutate(id = factor(row_number(),labels = dateOpened)) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = id, y = daysPrior))+
  labs(x = "Date Opened", y = "Days prior to opening at or above 11.0")
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!<br/>
Do you think the **geom_col** is the proper one to use? I also posted my original question on reddit and a responder didn't think it was the best to use. They suggested a scatterplot since the data is discrete points. I don't have a background in stats or data visualization. I thought with columns it was easy to see; I guess it is just as easy to see with a scatterplot.<br/>Curious for more input as I try to learn what's best.

Comment: In general, I agree that this is probably not the best visualization. The x-axis is confusing - It is a date, but we have manipulated here to exclude the numeric value from the date (i.e. distance between dates are not naturally  utilized)

Comment: A scatter, is possible too - I think it depends on what you are trying to communicate: you can mutate you dateOpened column to be a real date, and then try `ggplot(openingData, aes(dateOpened, daysPrior)) + 
  geom_point(size=4)+ ylim(0,100) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=daysPrior),nudge_y=3)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your dates to a factor, and order the factor levels according to the date they represent. This involves converting to a date, ordering, then converting back again.

```r
dates <- as.Date(openingData$dateOpened, format = "%m/%d/%y")
levs  <- strftime(sort(dates), format = "%m/%d/%y")
openingData$dateOpened <- factor(strftime(dates, format = "%m/%d/%y"), levs)
                                 

ggplot(data = openingData) +
    geom_col(mapping = aes(x = dateOpened, y = daysPrior)) +
    labs(x = "Date Opened", y = "Days prior to opening at or above 11.0")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it!

Do you think this is the best visualization for what I want to display?  I guess the one I had where the x-axis was dates may be best, but as I said I didn't like the big gaps.  

I posted the question on reddit, too, and a user there suggest a scatter plot.